# Azure table storage: concurrent updates overwritting previous changes

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, azure-tablequery

I have an program that updates entries in an Azure Table Storage table like this:

- recovers the entry from the table filtering by partitionKey and item Id
- makes some changes in some properties of the recovered object.
- saves changes back to BD.

Since I have read that Azure Storage tables use optimistic concurrency and the Etag property (for example according to [this](https://microsoft.github.io/AzureTipsAndTricks/blog/tip88.html), or this stackoverflow question [on what is stored in Etag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17441379/what-is-purpose-of-etag-in-itableentity))
to manage it I came up with this code:

```
var query = table.CreateQuery<DynamicTableEntity>()
                   .Where(d => d.PartitionKey == customItem.PartitionKey
                   && d.Properties[nameof(CustomItem.CustomItemId)].GuidValue == Guid.Parse(StringValueOfId)
                   )
                   .AsTableQuery();

            var tr = table.ExecuteQuery<DynamicTableEntity>(query);

            if (tr != null)
            {
                var entity = new DynamicTableEntity(customItem.PartitionKey, StringValueOfId);
                entity.Properties.Add("MyDate", dateValue);
                entity.Properties.Add("CustomProperty", new EntityProperty(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customItem)));
                entity.ETag = tr.FirstOrDefault().ETag;
                TableOperation mergeOperation = TableOperation.Replace(entity);
                try
                {
                    TableResult result = await table.ExecuteAsync(mergeOperation);
                    
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new StorageException("Error saving data:" + ex.Message);
                }

            }
```

Now I am still having issues with concurrency. Basically my "CustomProperty" has
a serialized property with some fields to null. It looks like, both A and B try
to set the the value of "CustomProperty" at the same time. And one of them is overwriting
the changes of the other.

Yet I expected that that would not be possible due to the settings of "entity.ETag".
I was expecting that if A, and B read at the same time of the BD, and then A updates,
the update of B would fail due to a mismatch of the value of entity.ETag.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? Did I not understand how to correctly avoid these
concurrencies issues?

Answer (score 0):

I found what the problem was. This line here had the wrong etag:

```
entity.ETag = tr.FirstOrDefault().ETag;
```

That is the *Etag* of when I read the row from the DB to recover the item to update, but actually I needed the *Etag* value of when I read the *customItem* property.

Otherwise, this line may overwrite any change that happen after I recovered the
*customItem*, but before I executed the query *var tr = table.ExecuteQuery(query);*

```
entity.Properties.Add("CustomProperty", new EntityProperty(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customItem)));
```

In other words, this solved my problem:

```
entity.ETag = customItem.ETag
```