# REST API - Concurrency Check Using ETags

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core-webapi

When building RESTful api, one approach to solve concurrency issues is by using ETags. For this to work, client must specify ETag with the request header.

If ETag is not present in the request header, what is the general practice? Do we just return a BadRequest? Do we also include the absence of ETag in the response to inform the client? Is there any approach where-in clients can be informed of actions that require specific headers?

Thanks in advance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If ETag is not present in the request header, what is the general practice? Do we just return a BadRequest?

RFC 6586 defines [428 Precondition Required](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6585#section-3):

```
The 428 status code indicates that the origin server 
requires the request to be conditional.
```

> Do we also include the absence of ETag in the response to inform the client?

Yes, just as you would for any other [client error in HTTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5).

```
Except when responding to a HEAD request, the server 
SHOULD send a representation containing an explanation 
of the error situation, and whether it is a temporary 
or permanent condition.
```

RFC 6585 includes this example

```
<html>
  <head>
     <title>Precondition Required</title>
  </head>
  <body>
     <h1>Precondition Required</h1>
     <p>This request is required to be conditional;
     try using "If-Match".</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

> Is there any approach where-in clients can be informed of actions that require specific headers?

I don't see any standard mechanism to communicate this to general purpose components.

The usual mechanism would, I believe, to communicate that information in response to an [OPTIONS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.7) request:

> A server generating a successful response to OPTIONS SHOULD send any header fields that might indicate optional features implemented by the server and applicable to the target resource (e.g., Allow), including potential extensions not defined by this specification. The response payload, if any, might also describe the communication options in a machine or human-readable representation.

Answer (score 1):

What [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag) says on ETag:

> An ETag is an opaque identifier **assigned by a Web server** to a specific version of a resource found at a URL. If the resource representation at that URL ever changes, a new and different ETag is assigned.

And then

> If the resource representation at that URL ever changes, a new and different ETag is assigned

With that said, it's should be clear that on `GET` requests, there should be no `ETag` presented, or it should not be taken into consideration by web server.
However, a response to `GET` request should contain the `ETag` which should be utilized on next entity's modification.

Actually, it can be presented in `GET` requests according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/ETag) if caching is involved, but as I can see from your question, it's not the case here?

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12399194/how-to-use-windows-azure-table-storage-timestamp-or-etag-field) you can read how `ETag` is utilized in Azure Table Storage. Note that ATS allows to omit `ETag`. In that case an ordinary updated will be performed. And that makes sense: allowing to omit `ETag` means more flexibility; programmer can decide where concurrency will be handled — by Azure Table Storage (utilizing `ETag`) or on the client side level, where calling side checks (or at least should odso) that requests do not run into concurrency issues.

Speaking of your RESTful api, that means that there is no general practice. You should decide are clients able to utilize your API without `Etag` or not, and if not — return appropriate error code. To notify client side that `ETags` should be used, you can return them with responses.